# share vnets between subscriptions in azure

Tags: vpn, azure, peering

Actually I have different Group resources using two subscriptions, but I need to enable access using IPsec VPN Gateway to all of them. I checked to use peering, but I see how if Group resource is in other subscription azure cli can't see them.

How can I mount a connection? I understand that you only can use one subscription to all the infrastructure to activate internal routing? All is in the same region.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, you have two Vnets in two subscription. If you enable Peering, the two Vnet could communication. But **VNet peering is between two virtual networks, and there is no derived transitive relationship.**

It seems that you have a Site-to-Site VPN from a local to one Vnet, it only works in the VNet, you could not communication to another VNet. You need create a new Site-to-Site VPN connection.

Comment: If you don't want to create VPN gateway and create a new site-to-site VPN connection. Maybe you could create a VM in the VNet and create use RRAS to create a site-to-site VPN. But it needs your VM always running.

Comment: Yes, I was checking docs (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-vnet-vnet-cli) where appears different environments and confirm that I need a site-to-site connection If I would like to use my schema. It's a surprise to need a VPN to connect two resources from same cloud in same region simply because there are in two group resources. I imagine in the future will change, because Im not the first to ask